# dnsPython - answer from dns.resolver.query

Tags: dns, resolver, dnspython

I need some help with getting nameserver (NS) records from specific domains.
So far i had no problem with my script but now I realised that it has
problem getting answer from domains like this: fpv.ukf.sk
With simple domain like google.com, ukf.sk etc. I have no problem.

used code:
answers = dns.resolver.query('fpv.ukf.sk', 'NS')

I get this error:
    answers = dns.resolver.query('fpv.ukf.sk', 'NS')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 920, in query
    raise_on_no_answer, source_port)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 858, in query
    raise_on_no_answer)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\dns\resolver.py", line 133, in **init**
    raise NoAnswer
NoAnswer

any suggestions why I cant get answer when I send query for fpv.ukf.sk domain?

Comment: but there really aren't any ``NS`` records under the "fpv.ukf.sk" domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you send any kind of query about the fpv.ukf.sk, you'll see that there is no answer. That is what the Python exception is showing you. So you are getting the expected behaviour.

Try to do:

```
nslookup fpv.ukf.sk -type=NS
```

By this you will be making a dns query to the nameserver which is configure in your system. If the authoritative server is a different one, you can to as follows.

```
nslookup fpv.ukf.sk <authoritative_nameserver> -type=NS
```

With this commands you can troubleshoot any dns query.